# How to add prop checked to dynamically added input(checkbox) when method is called

Tags: jquery

From my html:

```
<a href="#" id="scanCompleteBtn" class="btn btn-scan-nonactive">Scan To Complete
    <input value="" id='markOrderComplete' onChange="scanCompletedOrder(this)" type="text">
  </a>
```

I call the an onChange method `scanCompletedOrder(this)`
Inside this method I attempt to check a checkbox:

```
function scanCompletedOrder(orderId) {
  $( '#engraved_edges' ).prop('checked', true);
  postOrderStats(orderId.value);
  $( "#markOrderComplete" ).val('');
  onClickScanBtn("#scanSearchBtn", "#scanCompleteBtn", "#searchForScanner");
}
```

Problem is it doesn't get checked.

```
<input id="engraved_edges" type="checkbox" data-toggle="switch" data-shopify="data shopify"

              data-order="order number" class="ct-primary" value="0" />
```

Normally I would try to use an click and then change but in this case I'm not using jquery to handle the click I'm using the onChange method.  Is there anyway to accomplish this with the onChange method as shown above?

Comment: I have a suspicion from the `data-toggle` attribute that there is a script modifying that checkbox. Is that likely?

Comment: Yes it is being modified by a script.

Comment: That explains it then. You need to notify that script whatever it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'onkeyup' instead of 'onChange'.

```js
function scanCompletedOrder(orderId) {
  $( '#engraved_edges' ).prop('checked', true);
  //postOrderStats(orderId.value);
  //$( "#markOrderComplete" ).val('');
  //onClickScanBtn("#scanSearchBtn", "#scanCompleteBtn", "#searchForScanner");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="scanCompleteBtn" class="btn btn-scan-nonactive">Scan To Complete
<input value="" id='markOrderComplete' onkeyup="scanCompletedOrder(this)" type="text">
</a>


<input id="engraved_edges" type="checkbox" data-toggle="switch" data-shopify="data shopify" data-order="order number" class="ct-primary" value="0" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work.  I believe it's what the comment in the question above says.  It's being manipulated by another script.

Comment: Update that script as well to the question in that case.